# Vector Components

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

[Force System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHK0c.png)

For the vector force system in the photo, I am tasked with finding the component of $F = 600 \ lb$ along the $u$ direction. I originally tried to solve the problem by $$F_u = F \cos{\theta}$$ but when looking at the solution, I see that the law of sines was used such that $$\frac{F_u}{\sin{120}}=\frac{600}{\sin{30}}.$$ My question is, why can't you just find the component of $F$ in the $u$ direction by taking the cosine of the angle between them, like a dot product? The answer in the textbook was $F_u=1039 \ lb$. Interestingly, in this case the *component* has a greater magnitude than the *resultant*.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does ( 600 lb ) mean in your schema.

Comment: The 600 lb is pounds.